# How to Access URL Params in Django Channels Consumers

Tags: python, django, django-channels

If i had the following url in **routing.py**:

```
/rooms/<int:id>/
```

How would I access the id parameter from withing a JSONWebsocketConsumer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.scope['url_path']['kwargs']['id']
```

Comment: Even after changing `this` to `scope`, this fails on channels 3.0.5 with `KeyError: 'url_path'`

Answer (score 4):

I think the documentation needs updating, 'url_path' didn't work for me, but 'url_route' did.

```
self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['id']
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.

Answer (score 4):

To access any query param you can use;

for example socket URL = ws://localhost:8000/notifications?id=11

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
    
query_params = dict(parse_qsl(self.scope['query_string'].decode('utf-8')))
print(query_params['id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Get ID from the query param using;

```
self.scope['path'].split('/')[-2]
```

Comment: The answer assumes that the `ID` will be at a specific location. Please refer other answers and make it generic or flexible.

Comment: @AzharKhan I have answered the question above, thanks